# Evaluation order of chained numpy statements

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to understand/find out in which order chained `numpy` statements are evaluated. For example:

```
x = A.dot(B).dot(C)
```

Is it `(A.dot(B)).dot(C)` or `A.dot(B.dot(C))` or even `(A.dot(C)).dot(B)`?
Is there any way to see what happens in memory, what the interpreter's execution plan is or is there a general rule?

Comment: I know. Hoped it was easier to read that way. Fixed the example!

Comment: `numpy` is executed by python - normal python syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always give a reproducible example so that others can easily try things out on their computers. I do not know what `A`, `B`, or `C` are.

When methods are chained as you have it, the `.dot()` applies to the expression that immediately precedes it. You have `A.dot(B).dot(C)`, so the `.dot(B)` applies to A, and `.dot(C)` applies to the result of `A.dot(B)`. In other words, it is equivalent to `(A.dot(B)).dot(C)`. In order to see what the interpreter is doing, try the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html):

```
import ast
ast.dump(ast.parse("""A.dot(B).dot(C)"""))
```

and with some formatting, you get

```
Module(
    body=[
        Expr(
            value=Call(
                func=Attribute(
                    value=Call(
                        func=Attribute(
                            value=Name(id='A', ctx=Load()), 
                            attr='dot', 
                            ctx=Load()
                        ), 
                        args=[Name(id='B', ctx=Load())], 
                        keywords=[]
                    ), 
                    attr='dot', 
                    ctx=Load()
                ), 
                args=[Name(id='C', ctx=Load())], keywords=[])
            )
    ], type_ignores=[]
)
```

(note in Python 3.9, you can use the `indent` keyword on `ast.dump` to do the formatting automatically, i.e. `ast.dump(ast.parse("""A.dot(B).dot(C)"""), indent=4)`).

From the parsed version, you can see the inner most code is calling `A.dot(B)` first, then applying `.dot(C)` to that result.

To remove ambiguity, you can use `np.dot()` instead, i.e.

```
np.dot(np.dot(A, B), C)
```

to move from infix to prefix notation, as it were, to remove the ambiguity you see.

See the docs for numpy's `dot` [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html).

Comment: The way I'd express it is that `.dot` is a method of the array `A`.  The second `dot` is a method of the array produced by the first `dot`.

Comment: @James Pringle: Thanks for the very clear and understandable answer!